# Doubts concerning definition of set $C=\{\alpha<\omega_1:tp(\alpha\cap\textbf{LIM})=\alpha\}$

Tags: set-theory

I have problem with understanding definition of set: $C=\{\alpha<\omega_1:tp(\alpha\cap\textbf{LIM})=\alpha\}$

I do not know how to understand expression $tp(\alpha\cap\textbf{LIM})$. Is $tp(\alpha\cap\textbf{LIM})=\alpha$ for limit ordinals $\alpha$ and $tp(\alpha\cap\textbf{LIM})=0$ otherwise? So above set is set of ordinals smaller than $\omega_1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\alpha\cap LIM$ is the set of limit ordinals below $\alpha$; $tp(\alpha\cap LIM)$ is the ordertype of this set.

For example, if $\alpha=\omega^2$, then $LIM(\alpha)=\{\omega,\omega2,\omega3,...\}$, and $tp(\alpha\cap LIM)=\omega$.

As the above example shows, in general $tp(\alpha\cap LIM)$ is *much smaller* than $\alpha$ (since many ordinals $<\alpha$ are not limits). However, there are examples where $tp(\alpha\cap LIM)=\alpha$. For example, $\alpha=\omega^\omega$ has this property *(HINT: first show that for $n$ finite, $tp(\omega^{n+1}\cap LIM)= \omega^n$)*.

$C$ is just the set of such ordinals.

Comment: I followed your hint and now I need to ask a question in order to be sure that I've done everything correctly. $C$ is set of all ordinals of the form $\omega^\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is infinite, right?

Comment: I've never seen $\mathrm{tp}$ as an abbreviation for order type. I suspect that $\mathrm{tp}$ is meant to be read as **t**y**p**e, right?

Comment: @StefanMesken I have. It's rare, and I don't like it, but I have seen it.

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk No - consider $\omega^\omega+\omega^\omega$. It's more complicated than that. ([Cantor normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Cantor_normal_form) will be useful here, and in many questions of this type.)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that $\mathbf{LIM}$ stands for the collection of limit ordinals.

$C$ is then apparantly the collection of countable ($<\omega_1$) ordinals $\alpha$ that have the property that the type of their subset $\{\beta\in\alpha\mid \beta\text{ is a limit }\}$ equals $\alpha$.